# JMeter CSV Read and group the number of lines read

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have encounter a challenge where I have to read a CSV file and read it till a defined variable size limit( BATCH_SIZE). Once the no of lines from CSV has been read then send it to different AWS API. As my CSV file size can be anywhere 1Gb to 2Gb, therefore I am avoiding to use JSR223 CSV file read.
I want to know how can I can achieve it with JMeter and CSV Data Set Config.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can achieve it using CSV Data Set Config by putting it under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and using your `BATCH_SIZE` as the loop count.

Another option is importing your CSV file to the [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#RDBMS) and use JMeter's [JDBC Request sampler for accessing the data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-database-data-for-api-testing-with-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be by placing the CSV Data Set Config under a [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller).

`${__groovy(vars.get("__jm__WC__idx").toInteger()< vars.get("BATCH_SIZE").toInteger())}`

[image]